# Radio button selection from database in Visual Basic app

Tags: vb.net

I have 3 radio buttons in a frame. If I have a number in the database, I want to select the radio button depending on the number. Sorry if this is a duplicate question but I tried searching.

This seems to work randomly:

```
mABC = cboABC.SelectedValue
Select Case mABC
    Case 0
        optABC_ccc.Checked = True
    Case 1
        optABC_bbb.Checked = True
    Case 2
        optABC_aaa.Checked = True
```

Comment: what object is cboABC?

Comment: I filled the number I want into it. its a bit of a round about way of doing it but, the app uses the names minus prefix as a bookmark to fill the controls from the database.

Comment: What is the question? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong.

Comment: It doesn't work right, i have the cboABC showing either 0, 1 or 2, so the radio boxes should be optABC_ccc ticked when cboABC shows 0, but it doesn't work all the time.

Comment: I put this in the form load, at the end just before the return statement.

Comment: form load doesn't have a return statement

Comment: Public Function LoadForm() As Boolean

Comment: We can't see your IDE. I'm sure there's more code you could provide to clear some things up. Anyway, it appears that you aren't setting the `ValueMember` of cboABC. Have you debugged the code above? With a breakpoint on line `Select Case mABC`, what is the value of `mABC`?

Comment: i think its just in a wrong place in the code. but cant understand when why and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple example does what you want. I'm not sure where you went wrong. Try it out and see what your code is missing.

I have the same controls as you, plus a Button to call your code.

```
' class to be used as data source
Private Class Foo
    Public Property A As Integer
End Class

' set up data source, and set ValueMember (otherwise SelectedValue won't work)
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ds = New List(Of Foo)()
    ds.Add(New Foo() With {.A = 0})
    ds.Add(New Foo() With {.A = 1})
    ds.Add(New Foo() With {.A = 2})
    cboABC.DataSource = ds
    cboABC.ValueMember = "A"
End Sub

' used a button to initiate your code
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' SelectedValue is the value of property A of the data source
    ' this code is identical to yours
    Dim mABC = cboABC.SelectedValue
    Select Case mABC
        Case 0
            optABC_ccc.Checked = True
        Case 1
            optABC_bbb.Checked = True
        Case 2
            optABC_aaa.Checked = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
        mABC = ds.Tables("Alphabet").Rows(0)("ABC")
        'mABC = cboABC.SelectedValue
        Select Case mABC
            Case 0
                optABC_ccc.Checked = True
            Case 1
                optABC_bbb.Checked = True
            Case 2
                optABC_aaa.Checked = True

        End Select
```